# Clean 'Tabbing' system. (Javascript?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am here today to ask a question about live 'tabbing' what I mean is
I have a dashboard page on my website. [image]
And the buttons to the side is my main example however once the solution
to this problem is found I will have icons on the blank white right hand side too.

I need a way so that when an icon or button has been pressed the white space on
the side will be updated. So for example when the change password button has been
 pressed. It will update the content on the right. Again in the future there will be icons
In that area!

In this situation I do not belive any code here is necessary. As I belive none of the code
 I am using will be helpfull. (Please tell me if you want the code.)

Comment: You probably want to bind a click event handler to the buttons, e.g., `$('#myButton').on('click', function() { /* Update stuff */ }`. There's a ton of examples / reference available on this.

Comment: Any reason not to use [jQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) tabs? Do you know the contents of everything that might go in the white area on page load? Or do you need to load it on demand? For Yes; Have lots of Divs, all hidden. Show the required one when a button is clicked and hide the rest. For No; Have a single div in the white area whose content is loaded on demand via an Ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a purely academic method, it is possible. Here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/hL3mW/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li tabindex="0">A
        <div class="content">Cookies</div>
    </li><li tabindex="0">B
        <div class="content">Pie</div>
    </li><li tabindex="0">C
        <div class="content">Cake</div>
    </li><li tabindex="0">D
        <div class="content">Candy</div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="placeholder"></div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background: #9C3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

li div {
    display: none;
}

li:focus div {
    display: block;
}

div.content, div.placeholder {
    background: #CCC;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 2;
}

div.placeholder {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that if you assign a tabindex to anything, it can take focus, which you can then target using CSS pseudo-selectors (namely :focus).

This basically makes it so each `<li>` holds a div, which is normally hidden. Then, when the parent li gets focus, the div is shown and absolutely positioned over our target area. We have a dummy placeholder just to give the appropriate background, which is then overlapped by the visible content div.

However, from a practical viewpoint, this isn't really that good. If anything within the content is clickable and steals focus (links, butotns, inputs, etc), then the li will lose focus and it will be hidden.

Really it makes more sense to use a little JavaScript to add/remove classes which then control what does and does not show.